# Wifi no longer works after upgrading to Ubuntu 10.04 Lts

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04

My wifi connections no longer work after upgrading to 10.04. I am loading it on a Toshiba Tecra 9000. It does not work with either internal WIFI set up (as it did before) nor with a Linksys card. It recognizes the the router and ssid, it asks for passwords etc. When input, it tries to connect then keeps asking to input the wep passphrase or code. Drivers etc are upto date. nothing in the forums seems to work yet this seems like a problem many have had.

Works fine on wired connection. About to revert back to 9.10 unless someone can help.

Comment: similar issues reported.As of now, no solution.

Comment: Since Ubuntu is already widely used, it is a good idea to not upgrade instantly. Wait for a while, watch their forums and bug tracker for people complaining about problems with hardware like yours after upgrading. This way you won't have to waste time for reverting.

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for WEP passphrase?  Does your network actually use WEP or WPA, which has been standard for several years now?  Try opening the Connections dialog, edit the connection, and select the correct authentication method.

Answer (score -1):

Just plug it into wired net access and install drivers. It should come up on its own – if not, go to *System Settings*. You'll find it there.